# Is appending superscripts possible?

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

Let's say I want to write `N^{eT}`, but have `N^e` as a predefined command `\Ne`. Thus, I want to append the character `T` to the superscript of `\Ne`. Is this possible?

(Note that I don't want to write `{\Ne}^T`, since that will result in the T being one level above the e. This was adressed in [Trick LaTeX into doing double superscripts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5909/trick-latex-into-doing-double-superscripts) by the way)

Comment: It may help to explain how you intend to use the macro. Something along the lines of `\def\Ne#1{$N^{e#1}$}` is acceptable in your case? (usage: \Ne T)

Comment: What about using `$\Ne{}^T$` (maybe putting it into a box to prevent a break between `e` and `T`)?

Comment: Haha, I actually didn't know that was possible, Stephen. Thanks!

Comment: Similar question has been answered some time ago: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33261/defining-a-newcommand-with-sub-or-superscript-and-avoiding-double-subscript-e

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Or what about an empty optional argument?

```
\newcommand*\Ne[1][]{N^{e#1}}
```

Which you can use

```
$\Ne$ or $\Ne[T]$
```

Comment: Accepted for conciseness. Thanks to all responders!

Comment: By the way, what does the asterisk after "\newcommand" do?

Comment: @andreasdr: The starred variant of `\newcommand` removes the capability to include lengthy arguments (like paragraphs). Surely, since your superscripts will only contain characters (not paragraphs), using `\newcommand*` is appropriate.

Comment: @andreasdr: A more detailed explanation of `\newcommand*` can be found at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand

Answer (score 8):

Here is a "clever hack" inspired by (read: shamelessly copied from) the definition of math prime:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\Ne{N^\bgroup\e@s}
\def\e@s{%
  e\futurelet\@let@token\e@@s}
\def\e@@s{%
  \ifx^\@let@token
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\e@@@s
  \else
     \egroup
  \fi}
\def\e@@@s#1#2{#2\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\Ne^T \Ne^T_5
\]
\end{document}
```

You can do `\Ne^{}_{}` but not `\Ne_{}^{}`, otherwise the positioning is exactly as `N^{}_{}`

Answer (score 4):

I would define `\Ne` in the following way:

```
\newcommand{\Ne}{\ensuremath{N^e\vphantom{N}}}
```

This ensures that any following superscripts start at the same height as regular superscripts to `N`, but also trick TeX in thinking that it's *not* doubling a superscript:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Ne}{\ensuremath{N^e\vphantom{N}}}
\begin{document}
\Ne\ $\Ne^T$\ $N^{eT}$
\end{document}
```

Note that this will not work properly for subscripts, since the placement will be off. It would require more effort to make that work.